# Using different access method with thinktecture STS server

Tags: claims-based-identity, biometrics, thinktecture-ident-server

I'm currently new to Claim Based Model and Secure Token Service.

I have successfully installed thinktecture identity server and tested it.
The next step that i would like to make , is to change the login method from the normal method of user name and password to another biometric method (actually a fingerprint) ,

i.e. i would like to know how to make the thinktecture server to accept biometric data (where do I have to tune) rather than the user name and the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built-in for that. You would need to do that yourself. The obvious place to start would be the login view/controller.

Comment: Thanks alot for reply Mr.Dominick Baier, well do you mean that i need to modify the thinktecture STS in order to make "fingerprint aware", can you please give me a hint about the projects that i need to consider and modify, since the architecture of the thinktecture server is advanced and will need a considerable amount of time to be well understood.

Comment: I have searched throughout the internet, and I found this tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/482546/Creating-a-custom-user-login-form-with-NET-Csharp my question now, will it be enough to manipulate only the login logic? is n't there any for of dependency between the underlying STS logic and username/password access method?

Comment: The login page creates an identity - this identity is used in the token issuance process. There's no further coupling. Of course you also need to implement your own User and Claims repositories. You have to study the code, I can't save you from that ;)